# How convert .htaccess rewrite URL to web.config format

Tags: apache, .htaccess, iis, web-config

I have a php application that rely heavily on apache rewrite rule but I have to move the php application to IIS so I need to convert the .htaccess to web.config

Below is my .htaccess rules which get all the path and parameter after the domain name and rewrite to index.php file.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Below is my current web.config which give me a 505 internal server error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="rule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$"  />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="//index.php/{R:1}"  />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If your server returns 505 it should print some logs somewhere. Could you provide them? On the first look, nothing much seems wrong

Comment: As far as I know, the http 505 error. 505 error means "HTTP version not supported". That means the web server refused access your http version request. Could you please tell me do you access the page using special device?Like mobile?